# Spring Data - JPA Repository LIKE @Query for different type of entity fields

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How to write one custom like @Query for different types of entity fields. That mean according to following Entity class I have to write some custom search query by combing String fields and Date field. I am using PostgreSQL database and with my implantation I got following exception. Thanks.

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
}
```

**Service method**

```
public Iterable<User> searchByText(String searchText) {

    String likeExpression = "%" + searchText + "%";    
    Iterable<User> users = userRepository.searchByText(likeExpression);        
    return users ;       
}
```

**Repository method**

```
@Query("SELECT usr FROM User usr "
            + "WHERE lower(usr.name) like lower(:searchText) "
            + "OR lower(usr.description) like lower(:searchText)  "
            + "OR usr.createdOn like :searchText")
public List<User> searchByText(@Param("searchText") String searchText);
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:120)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:61)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 252
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
        ... 105 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From exception trace it seems, issue is due to 'like' operation on your date field.

You can use 'to_char(usr.createdOn,'ANY_DATE_TIME_FORMAT')' to convert the date to string in any date format and then use like for matching.

Comment: Hi Gupta ! Thanks for the feedback. I have tried this but it seems JPQL does not support a to_char function: http://www.coderanch.com/t/499205/ORM/databases/char-function-select-statement-JPQL. Functions which support with JPA: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#Functions

Comment: Hi Channa, what version of JPA you are using, it is working for me i am using JPA2.0.

Comment: Hi Gupta ! Thanks for the feedback. Yes as you mention it works for above JPA 2.0.  Thanks a lot for worth full answer. Have a nice time !